# Trigger email on lack of excel sharepoint edit interval

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I know I can create an alert in SharePoint every time a file is edited. Is there the facility or flow workflow to trigger email notifications if a file ISN'T edited for a specified amount of time e.g. 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are no triggers available in ms flow to check if a file isn't edited for a specified amount of time.

As a workaround, you could build a scheduled flow and make it to run every 5 mins. Iterate through each file in the document library check the property Modified.if now-Modified>= 30s
then send an email notification.